# Is the IAuthenticationManagerExtensions class gone in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 1.0 version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have updated Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin rc1 to the 1.0 version and I can not find the extensions methods to manage identity tokens.

Is the Token Management gone or is there another way to manage tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are still some extensions that are there mostly making it easier to extract out information from the external identities (i.e. google/fb username/emails).

Token Management is gone for 1.0 RTM, it will be back in 1.1 (it is in the nightly builds on myget)